# Stack Overflow will not allow me to post this table (code not formatted as code error)

Tags: bug, markdown, tables

When I post the following table into an answer on Stack Overflow, it gives me the "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. " error.

I was able to circumvent this by surrounding all the entries with backticks, but I'm curious as to why SO thinks this is code.

| Opr. short text | Act. start | Act. finish |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Generator Hochzeit | 04.11.2022 | 04.11.2022 |
| Generator Setup | 04.11.2022 | 04.11.2022 |
| Generator Dauertest | 04.11.2022 | 04.11.2022 |
| Generator Endkontrolle |  |  |
| Generator Hochzeit | 14.11.2022 | 14.11.2022 |
| Generator Setup |  |  |
| Generator Dauertest |  |  |
| Generator Endkontrolle |  |  |
| Generator Hochzeit | 21.11.2022 | 21.11.2022 |
| Generator Setup |  |  |
| Generator Dauertest |  |  |
| Generator Endkontrolle |  |  |
| Generator Hochzeit | 09.01.2023 | 09.01.2023 |
| Generator Setup |  |  |
| Generator Dauertest |  |  |
| Generator Endkontrolle |  |  |

My answer with this table (with the backticks) is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75375708/9852011

Comment: Although this is a known bug (see duplicates), I don't reproduce in this particular case. I don't know if that's because, as a moderator, the quality filter isn't applied to my edits (although I think it is). Either way, the post now looks correct. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray Thank you for the edit, it looks much nicer without the little code blocks in the table. My guess is "generator" must be one of the words that trigger the code recognition...

Comment: @CodyGray I don't want to bother you with this but I did some more testing and it appears it's actually the pipes without anything between them that trigger it. putting |||| on 3 rows trigger the error. Putting something between the pipes (ie. |a|a|a|) on just one of the 3 rows clears the error.